# Discord.js putting space between inventory items

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I'm using quick.db I want to have a little space between each item because if a user bought two items the items would view like "item1,item2" next to each other Is there a way to put space between them?

Inventory command's code

```js
 let hats = db.get(`${message.author.id}.userHats`)
        if(hats === undefined) hats = "none"
        let outfits = db.get(`${message.author.id}.userOutfits`)
        if(outfits === undefined) outfits = "none"
        let pets = db.get(`${message.author.id}.userPets`)
        if(pets === undefined) pets = "none"

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}\'s inventory`)
        .addField(`Hats`, `${hats}` || "none")
        .addField(`Outfits`, `${outfits}` || "none")
        .addField(`Pets`, `${pets}` || "none")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('#00ffff')
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        message.channel.send(embed)
```

How i push the items into "userHats"

```js
db.push(`${message.author.id}.userHats`, args[1])
```

the `args[1]` is the item name

would putting space between the items in the inv command require a different storing way?

EDIT: I store the data like in the sqlite file like this:

```
{
  balance: 2558,
  bank: 1898,
  skin: 'cyan',
  userHats: [ 'plaguedoctor', 'egg' ]
}
```

I tried to use `.join()` and just found it and gives the error "TypeError: outfits.join is not a function" because "outfits" the user doesn't have any of it and he had of "hats" removing the "outfits" and "pets" makes the command works because he only has hats, is there a way to make it ignore the empty or undefined ones? i tried `if(outfits === undefined) outfits = "none"` but it doesn't seem to be working and gives the same error
updated code:

```js
let hats = db.get(`${message.author.id}.userHats`)
        if(hats === undefined) hats = "none"
        let hats2 = hats.join(", ")
        
        let outfits = db.get(`${message.author.id}.userOutfits`)
        if(outfits === undefined) outfits = "none"
        let outfits2 = outfits.join(", ")
        
        let pets = db.get(`${message.author.id}.userPets`)
        if(pets === undefined) pets = "none"
        let pets2 = pets.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

If the items are stored as arrays such as:

```
outfits = [ outfit1, outfit2]
```

then you can use `outfits.join(', ')` to join the array's items with a `,`  between each one.

Alternatively, if your database stores it as a string, you can just do:

```
outfits.replace(',', ', ')
```

which would replace the first instance of `,` in the string with `,` .
However, since there are likely many items, you'll want to use regex to replace *all* instances of the comma, so that would instead look like:

```
outfits.replace(/,/g, ', ')
```

Either way, no need to worry about restructuring all your data since there are ways to make it display the way you want it to!

Comment: Tried the three of them they gave me error "outfits.replace is not a function" and "outfits.join is not a function" for the join() one, I also edited my question with the way the data is stored